# What to do flutter android x issue

Tags: flutter, androidx, flutter-dependencies

`firebase_auth ^0.7.0 and flutter_firebase_ui ^0.0.13, version solving failed.`
I don't want to move to android x anybody help me to solve this issue

> http: ^0.12.0
>      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
>      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
>       cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
>       #sqflite: any
>       sqflite: ^1.1.0
>       folding_cell: "^0.1.0"
>       flutter_rating: ^0.0.2
>       firebase_auth:  ^0.7.0
>       firebase_database: ^1.0.5
>       fluttertoast: ^2.1.5
>       progress_hud: ^1.1.0
>       auto_size_text: ^0.3.0
>       google_sign_in: ^3.0.4
>       material_search: ^0.2.8
>       flutter_secure_storage: ^3.1.2
>       modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.2
>       flutter_typeahead: ^0.4.1
>       flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
>       flutter_firebase_ui: ^0.0.13
>       json_serializable: ^2.0.1
>       flutter_spinkit: "^3.1.0"
>       #shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
>       flutter_html: ^0.8.2
>       flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.1.3
>       #location_picker: ^0.0.16
>       # google_maps_flutter: ^0.4.0
>       # google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3+3
>       #pinch_zoom_image: "^0.2.5"
>       #photo_view: ^0.2.0
>       splashscreen: ^1.1.0
>       #shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
>       badges: ^0.0.6
>       percent_indicator: ^1.0.14
>       #google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3
>       #flutter_google_places: ^0.1.4
>       #location: ^1.4.1
>       #location: ^2.0.0
>       #simple_permissions: ^0.1.9
>       #location_picker: ^0.0.16
>
> #need androidx
>       #geolocator: any
>       #geolocator: ^3.0.0
>       #google_places_picker: ^0.1.0
>       autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4
>       vibrate: ^0.0.4
>       cached_network_image: ^0.7.0
>       #google_maps_flutter: ^0.0.3
>       flutter_google_places: ^0.1.4
>       #location: ^1.4.1
>       #percent_indicator: "^1.0.14"
>       flutter_date_picker: "^0.1.8"
>       shared_preferences: 0.4.3

Answer (score 0):

You can [avoid from androidx](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx) by using these package versions, if you don't want to migrate your project.